# How to get the "anti-clockwise" angle between two 2D vectors?

Tags: math

I have two vectors and I want to get the angle between those vectors, I am currently doing it with this formula :

```
acos(dot(v1.unitVector, v2.unitVector))
```

Here is what I get with it :
[image]

I would want the green angle rather than the red angle, but I don't know what formula I should use...

Thank you.

EDIT : So, hen the vectors are still in a certain position (like the first two pairs of vectors, it's ok, but whenever it is in a configuration like in the third pair, it doesn't give me the right angle anymore)

Comment: It probably depends on the language/platform you're using.  Is the "red" answer negative?  If so you can just do `(360 + angle) MOD 360` (or 2*PI if your answer is in radians)

Comment: @DStanley The red angle is the one I don't want, what I want is to always get the angle by following an anti-clockwise rotation

Comment: I know, but if red_angle is negative, then `green_angle = 360 + red_angle = (360 + red_angle) MOD 360`.  If your answer is positive (like purple_angle), then `(360+purple_angle) MOD 360` will still give you purple_angle. So it works for all cases (positive or negative)

Comment: @DStanley Unfortunately I doesn't work either !

Comment: You might try taking the inverse sine of the cross product instead of the dot product, making sure to choose the order so the right hand rule with the normal out of the plane.

Comment: this question would have been more suitable at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the dot product you get always an angle that is independent of the order of the vectors and the smaller of the two possibilities.

For what you want, you need the argument function of complex numbers that is realized by the `atan2` function. The angle from `a=ax+i*ay` to `b=bx+i*by` is the argument of the conjugate of `a` times `b` (rotating `b` backwards by the angle of `a`, scale not considered), which in coordinates is

```
(ax-i*ay) * (bx+i*by) = ax*bx+ay*by + i*(ax*by-ay*bx)
```

so the angle is

```
atan2( ax*by-ay*bx, ax*bx+ay*by ).
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: that works only in 2D ... in 3D you have to project to common plane or use `acos + dot product` then construct rotated vector do a CW/CCW check and correct resulting angle if needed.

Comment: After searching high and low, this is the only answer that explained everything.

Comment: This would return a negative angle if the counterclockwise angle is larger than 180 degrees. To get a result of 0~360 degrees, add 360 degrees to the result if the result is negative.

Comment: This is discussed extensively in the other answers, there would be no information gain to add that here.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the accepted answer, the problem with `atan2` is that, if you imagine vector `a` being static and vector `b` rotating in anti-clockwise direction, you will see the return value ranging from 0 to π, but then it suddenly turns negative and proceeds from -π to 0, which is not exactly good if you're interested in an angle increasing from 0 to 2π.

To tackle that problem, the function below conveniently maps the result from `atan2` and returns a value between 0 and 2π as one would expect:

```js
const TAU = Math.PI * 2;

/**
 * Gives the angle in radians from vector a to vector b in anticlockwise direction, 
 * ranging from 0 to 2π.
 * 
 * @param {Vector} a
 * @param {Vector} b
 * @returns {Number}
 */
static angle(a, b) {
    let angle = Math.atan2(a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x, a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y);
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += TAU;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

It is written in JavaScript, but it's easily portable to other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Lutz already answered this correctly but let me add that I highly recommend basing modern vector math code on Geometric Algebra which raises the abstraction level dramatically.

Using GA, you can simply multiply the two vectors U and V to get a rotor. The rotor internally looks like A + Bxy where A = U dot V = |U|V|cos(angle) and Bxy = U wedge V = |U||V|sin(angle)xy (this is isomorphic to the complex numbers). Then you can return the rotor's signed CCW angle which is atan2( B, A ).

So with operator overloading, you can just type (u * v).Angle. The final calculations end up the same, but the abstraction level you think and work in is much higher.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one is more fit:

```
atan2( ax*by-ay*bx, ax*bx+ay*by ) % (PI*2)
```

the calculation which could get the full anti-clockwise radian.

Comment: % (euclidean modulo) doesn't work when values are negative, you would have to do: ((angle % tau) + tau) % tau  where tau is 2 * pi